# Difficulty summing the elements of a 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

I have a vector of vectors that gives me a n x n matrix. I am using a for loop to sum all the elements in the matrix and I am getting weird results.

The relevant code is:

```
int main(){
while(cin){

int n = 0;
int sum = 0;

cout << "\n\nEnter a size (n) for the matrix: ";
cin >> n;

vector<vector<int> > matrix ( n, vector<int> ( n ) );
int k = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        matrix[i][j] = k++;
}

for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        cout<< setw ( 3 ) << matrix[i][j] <<' ';
        cout<<'\n';
}

for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        sum += matrix[i][j];
}
cout << "\nThe sum of the elements of the matrix is: " << sum << ' \n';
}
}
```

So, what's weird is...when it prints the value of 'sum', for some reason, I am getting "8202" appended to the value. If I given it n = 1, it will print out 08202, or for n of 3 it will print out 368202.

Any ideas? I tried the debugger in Code::Blocks w/o success.

Comment: Just so you know, there's an algorithm, `std::accumulate` meant for this.

Comment: Doesn't seem to play nice with a vector of vectors. Or rather, if it does (or should), I can't seem to implement it properly.

Comment: Please show a more complete code example. (preferably completely complete)

Comment: @Kickasstimus, That vector of vectors should be just 1 vector.

Comment: Did you initialize sum with zero?

Comment: I don't like your `' \n'`, is that a space? Try removing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You output `' \n'`. Note the space before the `\n`. That's two characters/a string. However, you put `'`s around it meaning it interprets two characters as one character giving you strange results. Change it to `" \n"`.

BONUS EPIC-PHUNZIES CONTENT: How did I figure it out? Well... what else could it be? The sum outputted correctly so something must be wrong after it. And what's the only thing after you output sum? You output `' \n'`... well, what's wrong with that? And *BAM!* Problem solved.

Comment: Yeah, I dunno what I was thinking putting that in there like that...and then trying to debug it...and then posting it here...I blame it on lack of coffee/sleep/sanity

Comment: Heh. Yeah, don't worry. We all have those 3 hours <=> 2 character fix moments.